# Angular v14 - Error Carrousel owl-carousel no muestra los datos a menos que clickee sobre el contenedor

Tags: angular

espero que anden bien , me encuentro con el siguiente problema , como dice el titulo estoy implementando el carrousel en mi app de angular, carga y funciona correctamente. El unico problema que me tiene dando vueltas desde ayer es que no me muestra los datos a menos que le haga click sobre el contenedor que lo alberga

Asi se ve la imagen cuando carga la page:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y asi se ve cuando clickeo entre medio de los 'Some tags...'

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

a continuacion dejo mi codigo html y mi ts

HTML

```
<div>Some tags before</div>
    <owl-carousel-o class="carrousel-options" [options]="customOptions">
        <ng-template carouselSlide><a>Slide 1</a></ng-template>
        <ng-template carouselSlide><a>Slide 2</a></ng-template>
        <ng-template carouselSlide><a>Slide 3</a></ng-template>
    </owl-carousel-o>
    <div>Some tags after</div>
```

y este es mi Ts

```
customOptions: OwlOptions = {
  loop: true,
  mouseDrag: true,
  touchDrag: true,
  pullDrag: true,
  dots: true,
  navSpeed: 700,
  navText: ['', ''],
  responsive: {
    0: {
      items: 1
    },
    10: {
      items: 2
    },
    101: {
      items: 3
    }
  },
  nav: true
}
```

Comment: Edita la pregunta, agrega la directiva de `carouselSlide`, agrega todo lo mínimo necesario para reproducir tu escenario.

Comment: que versión del `owl-carousel` es?

Answer (score 0):

El problema ocasionado se debia a que me faltaba una importacion de `BrowserAnimationsModule` en mi app.module.ts

Lo que resultaba en un mal funcionamiento de mi owl-carrousel como tardar en cargar mis filtros